# Angular calling API with observable is not displaying data

Tags: json, angular, observable

I have implemented an angular 5 application to bring data from a Web API. I am using an observable to get the json. The Json coming from the API looks like this:

```
{
 "Job": [
 {
  "Title": "Solution Architect",
  "Summary": "Solution Architect",
  "Salary": {
    "MinValue": "100",
    "MaxValue": "100",
    "Text": "",
    "Period": "HourlyRate"
  },      
  "Reference": "234483_1",
},
{
  "Title": "Senior Business Analyst – eCommerce ",
  "Summary": "Senior Business Analyst...",
  "Salary": {
    "MinValue": "80",
    "MaxValue": "100",
    "Text": "",
    "Period": "HourlyRate"
  },      
  "Reference": "234874_1",
}
],
"Advertiser": "Resourcing",
"Source": "Wiz"
}
```

I have created a service looks as follows:

```
  ....
  @Injectable()
  export class AdvDataService {
  private _getAddsUrl = 'https://xx.xxxx.com/v1/adverts/www111';

 constructor(private _http: Http) { }

 getAdvForClient(): Observable<IAdv> {
   return this._http.get(this._getAddsUrl)
    .map((response: Response) => <IAdv>response.json()) 
    .do(data => console.log('All:' + data))
    .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

The component looks like that:

```
....
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(private _sdvDataService: AdvDataService) { }

private loadAdverts: IAdv;
private errorMesage: string;

ngOnInit() {
this.errorMesage = "";
this._sdvDataService.getAdvForClient()
    .subscribe(adv => {
        this.loadAdverts = adv;
       console.log ("here:"  + this.loadAdverts)
    }, error => {
        this.errorMesage = <any>error;        
    });
 }

}
```

I have a simple interface:

```
export interface IAdv {

Advertiser: string,
Source:string

}
```

and my html:

```
<div  *ngIf="loadAdverts" >
<div class="row justify-content-center">
  <div class="card" style="width: 20rem;">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h4 class="card-title">here: {{loadAdverts.Advertiser}}</h4>
      <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">{{loadAdverts.source}} </h6>
      <p class="card-text">{{loadAdverts.source}}</p> 
      <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
      <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I can see the json displayed in the console from both console.log in the component and in the service but any data is displayed in the view.

I would appreciate any help?

**Update**: It seems the json coming from the server is a json string. So it is not being parsed in the observable. I had to use json.parse in the suscriber. How can I parse that json string to a json object automatically with the suscriber?

Comment: in your json one of your json properties is `Source` but in your html you have `loadAdverts.source`

Comment: yes. I tried both loadAdverts.source and loadAdverts.Source but any of them work

Comment: can you try `IAdv[]` in place of `IAdv` ?

Comment: does the html between your `*ngIf="loadAdverts"` render? If so, your json properties might not be matching up

Comment: @LLai. yes it renders and I can see results in the chrome console which i am printing from the component  and from the service

Comment: so `this.loadAdverts` is getting set. Is it possible your json is wrapped in brackets `[]`

Comment: if query the api directly from the browser the results looks like that: <string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
{"Job":[{"Title":"Solution Architect","Summary":.......
</string> Dont know if that wrapper is the problem

Comment: probably you need to return `response.json().job` and cast it to array of  the right object type, in the same time extract response.json().Source, ....

Comment: .job is just a property there are other properties on the same level such as source or advertiser which are the ones i am trying to display.

Comment: @HDJEMAI However i tried but it is null.

Comment: You said you can console out the data? If `this.loadAdverts` is parsed json then `console.log('here: ' + this.loadAdverts)` should print out `here: [object Object]`. If it is printing out `here: {"Job": [{...`, then it sounds like your json was not parsed

Comment: @LLai exactly.  the json is not being parsed. I just re-parsed it gain using JSON.parse in the suscriber and i can see the data now. it Seems the json coming back is not a json object, it is a kind of json string. How can i parse automatically that using the observable?

Comment: It sounds like the API is returning XML. (I'm not too familiar with XML). I'd say the solution is to get the API to return proper json

Answer (score 0):

Your `loadAdverts` is a private variable and thus not accessible in the template.

Either make it public like this.

`public loadAdverts:IAdv;`

or use getters and setters.

```
private _loadAdverts:IAdv;
   ....

get loadAdverts(): IAdv {
 return this._loadAdverts;
}

set loadAdverts(_ad: IAdv) {
 this._loadAdverts = _ad;
}

   ....
```

Comment: Changed it to public but the same, not results displayed.

Comment: In that case try injecting changeDetectorRef like this.`constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef...)`  and then call `this.ref.detectChanges()` at the end of your `subscribe` handler.

Comment: i did something like that: this._sdvDataService.getAdvForClient()
        .subscribe(adv => {
            this.loadAdverts = adv;
           console.log ("here:"  + this.loadAdverts)
        }, error => {
            this.errorMesage = <any>error;        
        });
        this.ref.detectChanges()  but the same, no data.

Comment: Try this: `this._sdvDataService.getAdvForClient() .subscribe(adv => { this.loadAdverts = adv; console.log ("here:" + this.loadAdverts); this.ref.detectChanges();}, error => { this.errorMesage = <any>error; });`

Answer (score 0):

As we can see, you are receiving an Object `Job` containing an array, so you should extract that array from the object:

```ts
getAdvForClient(): Observable<IAdv> {
  return this._http.get(this._getAddsUrl)
    .map((response: Response) => <IAdv>response.json().Job) // here!
    .do(data => console.log('All:' + data))
    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

also, since you are getting an array, you would want to iterate that in your template:

```html
<div *ngFor="let adv of loadAdverts">
  <p>{{adv.Source}}</p>
  <!-- more code here -->
</div>
```

also notice that this is case sensitive, in your template you used `source` as the property name instead of `Source`.